# Image brightness contrast seekbar

Tags: java, android, seekbar, brightness, contrast

I am developing an app, that i want to implement some "filters" like contrast/brightness/hue etc. All these changes i want to get done through seekbar valuechanged. All of examples found here, are not smooth at all for realtime change through seekbar and it is not optimized for 12mpxl and above photos. I want something like instagram's manual adjustments, that is perfectly smooth.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this.You can adjust brightness,contrast,hue etc. with ColorMatrix.

```
import android.graphics.ColorFilter;
import android.graphics.ColorMatrix;
import android.graphics.ColorMatrixColorFilter;

public class ColorFilterGenerator {

private static double DELTA_INDEX[] = {
        0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.1, 0.11,
        0.12, 0.14, 0.15, 0.16, 0.17, 0.18, 0.20, 0.21, 0.22, 0.24,
        0.25, 0.27, 0.28, 0.30, 0.32, 0.34, 0.36, 0.38, 0.40, 0.42,
        0.44, 0.46, 0.48, 0.5, 0.53, 0.56, 0.59, 0.62, 0.65, 0.68,
        0.71, 0.74, 0.77, 0.80, 0.83, 0.86, 0.89, 0.92, 0.95, 0.98,
        1.0, 1.06, 1.12, 1.18, 1.24, 1.30, 1.36, 1.42, 1.48, 1.54,
        1.60, 1.66, 1.72, 1.78, 1.84, 1.90, 1.96, 2.0, 2.12, 2.25,
        2.37, 2.50, 2.62, 2.75, 2.87, 3.0, 3.2, 3.4, 3.6, 3.8,
        4.0, 4.3, 4.7, 4.9, 5.0, 5.5, 6.0, 6.5, 6.8, 7.0,
        7.3, 7.5, 7.8, 8.0, 8.4, 8.7, 9.0, 9.4, 9.6, 9.8,
        10.0
};

public static ColorFilter adjustHue(float value) {
    ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();

    adjustHue(cm, value);

    return new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);
}

public static ColorFilter adjustExposure(float value) {
    ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();

    adjustExposure(cm, value);

    return new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);
}

public static ColorFilter adjustTemperature(int r, int g, int b) {
    ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();

    adjustTemperature(cm, r, g, b);

    return new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);
}

public static ColorFilter adjustContrast(float value) {
    ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();

    //adjustContrast(cm, value);

    setContrast(cm, value);

    return new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);
}

public static ColorFilter adjustSaturation(int value) {
    ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();

    adjustSaturation(cm, value);

    return new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);
}

public static ColorFilter adjustBrightness(int value) {
    ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();

    adjustBrightness(cm, value);

    return new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);
}

public static void adjustHue(ColorMatrix cm, float value) {
    value = cleanValue(value, 180f) / 180f * (float) Math.PI;
    if (value == 0) {
        return;
    }
    float cosVal = (float) Math.cos(value);
    float sinVal = (float) Math.sin(value);
    float lumR = 0.213f;
    float lumG = 0.715f;
    float lumB = 0.072f;
    float[] mat = new float[]
            {
                    lumR + cosVal * (1 - lumR) + sinVal * (-lumR), lumG + cosVal * (-lumG) + sinVal * (-lumG), lumB + cosVal * (-lumB) + sinVal * (1 - lumB), 0, 0,
                    lumR + cosVal * (-lumR) + sinVal * (0.143f), lumG + cosVal * (1 - lumG) + sinVal * (0.140f), lumB + cosVal * (-lumB) + sinVal * (-0.283f), 0, 0,
                    lumR + cosVal * (-lumR) + sinVal * (-(1 - lumR)), lumG + cosVal * (-lumG) + sinVal * (lumG), lumB + cosVal * (1 - lumB) + sinVal * (lumB), 0, 0,
                    0f, 0f, 0f, 1f, 0f,
                    0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1f};
    cm.postConcat(new ColorMatrix(mat));
}

public static void adjustContrast(ColorMatrix cm, int value) {
    value = (int) cleanValue(value, 100);
    if (value == 0) {
        return;
    }
    float x;
    if (value < 0) {
        x = 127 + value / 100 * 127;
    } else {
        x = value % 1;
        if (x == 0) {
            x = (float) DELTA_INDEX[value];
        } else {
            //x = DELTA_INDEX[(p_val<<0)]; // this is how the IDE does it.
            x = (float) DELTA_INDEX[(value << 0)] * (1 - x) + (float) DELTA_INDEX[(value << 0) + 1] * x; // use linear interpolation for more granularity.
        }
        x = x * 127 + 127;
    }

    float[] mat = new float[]
            {
                    x / 127, 0, 0, 0, 0.5f * (127 - x),
                    0, x / 127, 0, 0, 0.5f * (127 - x),
                    0, 0, x / 127, 0, 0.5f * (127 - x),
                    0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 1
            };
    cm.postConcat(new ColorMatrix(mat));

}

private static void setContrast(ColorMatrix cm, float contrast) {
    float scale = contrast + 1.f;
    float translate = (-.5f * scale + .5f) * 255.f;
    cm.set(new float[]{
            scale, 0, 0, 0, translate,
            0, scale, 0, 0, translate,
            0, 0, scale, 0, translate,
            0, 0, 0, 1, 0});
}

public static void adjustSaturation(ColorMatrix cm, float value) {
    value = cleanValue(value, 100);
    if (value == 0) {
        return;
    }

    float x = 1 + ((value > 0) ? 3 * value / 100 : value / 100);
    float lumR = 0.3086f;
    float lumG = 0.6094f;
    float lumB = 0.0820f;

    float[] mat = new float[]
            {
                    lumR * (1 - x) + x, lumG * (1 - x), lumB * (1 - x), 0, 0,
                    lumR * (1 - x), lumG * (1 - x) + x, lumB * (1 - x), 0, 0,
                    lumR * (1 - x), lumG * (1 - x), lumB * (1 - x) + x, 0, 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 1
            };
    cm.postConcat(new ColorMatrix(mat));
}

public static void adjustBrightness(ColorMatrix cm, float value) {
    value = cleanValue(value, 100);
    if (value == 0) {
        return;
    }

    float[] mat = new float[]
            {
                    1, 0, 0, 0, value,
                    0, 1, 0, 0, value,
                    0, 0, 1, 0, value,
                    0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 1
            };
    cm.postConcat(new ColorMatrix(mat));
}

public static void adjustTemperature(ColorMatrix cm, int r, int g, int b) {

    cm.set(new float[]{
            r / 255.0f, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, g / 255.0f, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, b / 255.0f, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 1, 0});
}

public static void adjustExposure(ColorMatrix cm, float value) {
    value = cleanValue(value, 100);
//        if (value == 0) {
//            return;
//        }
//
//        float[] mat = new float[]
//                {
//                        value, 0, 0, 0, 0,
//                        0, value, 0, 0, 0,
//                        0, 0, value, 0, 0,
//                        0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
//                };
//        cm.postConcat(new ColorMatrix(mat));
     cm.set(new float[]{
            value, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, value, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, value, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
    });
}

protected static float cleanValue(float p_val, float p_limit) {
    return Math.min(p_limit, Math.max(-p_limit, p_val));
}
}
```

Just use it inside onProgressChanged.For example-

```
 mainImageView.setColorFilter(ColorFilterGenerator.adjustContrast(progress));
```

Comment: Thanks for answering me @Singh. Your answer with a little editting, was that i wanted! Editing was to put the result at Canvas, in order to be smooth. Thanks again.